# Как убрать лишние символы со строки?

Tags: java, android, строки

Есть строка: `String a = "[49,54545. 45,434324]";`. Надо убрать из неё символы `[` и `]`.

Наткнулся на метод `replaceAll()`, который, вроде, подходит. Попробовал удалить — смог удалить последний символ, но при попытке удаления первого символа — ошибка. Какие еще способы есть?

- `System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("[", ""));` не сработал.
- `System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("]", ""));` сработал, смог убрать последний элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `replaceAll()` нужно так:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String text = "[49,54545. 45,434324]";
    String nexText = text.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
    System.out.println(nexText);
}
```

Можно использовать регулярные выражения. Полученная строка будет содержать все символы старой, кроме `"["` и `"]"`.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String text = "[49,54545. 45,434324]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\[\\]]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while(m.find()) {
        builder.append(text.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    }
    String newText = builder.toString();
    System.out.println(newText);
}
```

Ещё можно взять срез строки без первого и последнего символов.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String text = "[49,54545. 45,434324]";
    String newText = text.substring(1, text.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(newText);
}
```

Comment: а какой из них  лучше ?в плане скорости

Comment: Строки будет всегда такого вида? Если, например, строка придёт без скобок. Второй способ порежет числа, а первый обработает нормально. Второй способ не удалит скобки внутри строки, если они ам\\там будут. Если уверены, что нужно удалять всегда только первый и последний символы, используйте второй способ. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616066/performance-comparision-between-substring-vs-regex-when-start-index-is-known

Comment: Да Всеже за динамическое изменение отвечать я немогу ))) так что воспользуюсь 1 методом )Можете сказать что  вы там сделали в 1 методе  в какую сторону капать ?как задали именно [] знаки ,что за тему мне прочитать

Comment: Перед квадратными скобками поставлено \\, чтобы указать, что это не спец. символ, а обычный. А ^ означает, что искать надо все символы, кроме тех, что идут дальше. http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2015/02/19/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-Java.html

Comment: спасибо щас почитаю !

Comment: Дополнил пример с использованием replaceAll(). Там тоже нужно было использовать регулярное выражение. Наверно, это будет самый оптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать ещё короче через цикл for.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String text = "[49,54545. 45,434324]";
    String newStr = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < text.length() - 1; i++) {
        newStr += text.charAt(i) != '[' && text.charAt(i) != ']' ? text.charAt(i) : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте объект класса StringBulder для собирания строки вместо конкатенации. https://ideone.com/z2QFTS

Comment: @КириллМалышев , можно поинтересоваться, в чём разница? Ведь результат будет одинаков. Хотя вроде припоминаю, что в книге у Шилдта было сказано, что строки нельзя изменять.

Comment: Да, иначе происходит каждый раз создание новой строки. Это сказывается на производительности. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927630/java-string-concat-vs-stringbuilder-optimised-so-what-should-i-do

Comment: @КириллМалышев, спасибо, прошу прощения за невнимательность.

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления скобок можно просто использовать функцию **replace**:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String text = "[49,54545. 45,434324]";
    text = text.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    System.out.println(text);
}
```